# Select distinct by highest or lowest value

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I'm working on a track and field ranking database in MySQL/PHP5 whereby I'm struggling to find the best way to query results per unique athlete by highest value.

just

```
SELECT distinct name, event
FROM results
```

sample database

```
name      | event | result
--------------------------
athlete 1 | 40    | 7.43
athlete 2 | 40    | 7.66
athlete 1 | 40    | 7.33
athlete 1 | 60    | 9.99
athlete 2 | 60    | 10.55
```

so let's say that in this case I'd like to rank the athletes on the 40m dash event by best performance I tried

```
SELECT distinct name, event
FROM results
WHERE event = 40
ORDER by result DESC
```

but the distinct only leaves the first performance (7.43) of the athlete which isn't the best (7.33). Is there an easy way other than creating a temp table first whereby the results are ordered first and performing a select on the temp table afterwards?

Comment: Should you be using 'min' and 'group by' in place of distinct?

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in `group by`:

```
SELECT name, min(result) as result
FROM results
WHERE event = 40
GROUP BY name
```

This gives you the best result per athlete.

As suggested by [spencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/107744/spencer7593), you can also order the list by appending this:

```
ORDER BY min(result) ASC
```

Comment: I think OP also wants to "rank" the results, which suggests OP would want to add `ORDER BY min(result) ASC` to the query.

Comment: @spencer7593, good catch! Updated the answer. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Thx @AlexTartan

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the columns used in the `ORDER BY` aren't specified in the `DISTINCT`. To do this, you need to use an aggregate function to sort on, and use a `GROUP BY` to make the `DISTINCT` work.

```
SELECT distinct name, event
FROM results
WHERE event = 40
GROUP BY name
ORDER by result DESC
```